# Joomla 2.5 custom mvc component: different form for task add

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm developing a custom mvc component for Joomla 2.5.

For my admin section I included a "New" button in the toolbar.
By clicking this button I want to display a separate form with less
fields. So far everything works out but the buttons of the view's 
toolbar won't redirect (i.e. 'Cancel')

To redirect the task 'add' I added an override of the method "add()"
to my controller:

```
class ArchitectProjectControllerArchitectProject extends JControllerForm
{
    public function add()
    {
        JRequest::setVar('layout',  'add');
        $result = parent::add();
    return $result;
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm on the right track. Probably someone can give me a hint?

Comment: Offtopic: You really selected a long name for your project. Can Architect be anything else but a Project? Do you also have like ArchitectTask ,etc?

Comment: there are also sections that can be associated to a project. They are called ArchitectSections.

Comment: is `Architect` is in every class name as prefix, it makes sense to remove it :) doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to redirect for example on 'Cancel' then try the following in the controller:

```
public function cancel()
{
   $this->setRedirect('index.php?option='.$this->option.'&view=yourview');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your fast replay. The cause of the problem was something different. The redirect worked fine but I forgot the form tag in the view.